# What permission is required to reorder SQL Server table columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant

Using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio, I can create or delete column but I can not reorder column order.

I get the error that this change requires the table to be dropped and re-created and I have not permission to do that. What permission should I have and how should I grant it using a query or using SMSS?

Comment: You are reordering the columns via SSMS right?

Comment: Yes by drag and drop @Sami

Comment: You need to make some changes in the options, I don't think you need `grant`

Comment: The order of columns doesn't make any difference anyway so why bother? And yes that is correct, you actually cannot change the column order. What really happens in SSMS is it creates a new table with the new column order, inserts the existing data in the new table, drops the existing table and then renames the new one to the old table name. But again....the order of columns in completely irrelevant for anything.

Comment: This is an option in SSMS not a permission. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/save-not-permitted-dialog-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need any permission here as I say before, all what you need is:

Go to `Options` -> `Designer` -> uncheck `prevent saving changes that require a table creation`

Comment: The OP may not actually have permission to drop/create tables which is what "reordering" columns requires.

Comment: How smart is SSMS? If OP has the necessary permissions AND there is data present AND `prevent saving changes` is True AND only the order is being modified, is SSMS able to realize that no data is being changed? (Too many "ands". I hope it's just lack of CREATE/ALTER TABLE permissions.)